# Why is the derivative of $\tan x$ expressed as $\sec^2 x$, introducing another function, instead of just $1+\tan^2x$?

Tags: calculus

Why is the derivative of $\tan(x)$ given in textbooks and other places as $\sec^2(x)$ instead of $1+\tan^2(x)$? Why bring other functions such as the secant into it? $1+\tan^2(x)$ expresses the derivative of the tangent in terms of the tangent.

Comment: Sometimes one expression is more useful than the other, that's all there is to it. It is good to remember both and choose the one that fits the best for a given problem.

Comment: It's pretty weird for beginning students to see that differentiating $\tan(x)$ produces a constant term ($1$) when differentiation usually kills constants

Comment: To save paper, and to control pollution. Both $1+tan²{x}$ and $sec²x$ are  same. So why shall we use more paper to send the same information.?

Comment: .... or $1 + \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$, or ...

Comment: @failedentertainment just use the engineer's approximation $\tan(x)\approx x$ *mathematicians wailing*

Comment: My guess is it's because thats what you get when you do it by substitution.

Comment: I find it interesting that, just as $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are related both Pythagoreanally(?) and differentially, so too are $\sec x$ and $\tan x$ (and $\csc x$ and $\cot x$). Further, we have: 
$$\frac{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{blue}{\sin x}}{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{red}{\cos x}}=-\frac{\color{red}{\cos x}}{\color{blue}{\sin x}}\qquad
\frac{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{blue}{\sec x}}{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{red}{\tan x}}=\frac{\color{red}{\tan x}}{\color{blue}{\sec x}}\qquad \frac{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{blue}{\csc x}}{\tfrac{d}{dx}\color{red}{\cot x}}=\frac{\color{red}{\cot x}}{\color{blue}{\csc x}}$$

Comment: I suspect that the answer is "[Tradition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdfX7ut8gw)"